# Avoiding heap allocation with "throwing" constructors

Tags: c++

Say I have some class `Foo` which does not define a default constructor and `throws` in a non-default constructor.  When initializing a new object of the type, I'd like to catch any exceptions and return, otherwise continue using the object.  I'm noticing it difficult, if at all possible, to initialize this object *on the stack* or through use of a shared pointer, because I'm trying to avoid managing memory.

**Fail 1**

```
Foo f; // doesn't work, no default constructor
try { f = Foo(...); }
```

**Fail 2**

```
try {
  Foo f(...)
}
catch(...) {}
// doesn't work, f is inaccessible
```

**Fail 3**

```
boost::shared_ptr<Foo> pf;
try { pf = new Foo(...); } // no assignment operator
```

**Must I...**

```
Foo *f;
try { f = new Foo(...) } // okay, let's just manage the memory
```

Is there a way?

**Edit**

Okay, so this works, albeit not the cleanest.  Is there a more "standard" way?

```
boost::shared_ptr<Foo> pf;
try { pf = boost::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(...)); }
```

Comment: From one point of view this makes sense; if you *could* do this, then it would mean that you could also carry on through the function with a stack-based object that had failed to be constructed...

Comment: Your icon is awesome. It looks like sharks eating a box.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Didn't even consider that.  Touché, Sir.

Comment: @aardvarkk Wow, they're not all the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach to keep `f` stack-based is to respect the scope:

```
try {
  Foo f(...);
  ... entire code using f ...
}
catch(...) {}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree this is **the** correct approach.  `... entire code using f ...` could be quite long, if not most of the body of `main()`, which commonly initializes a lot of objects that provide the foundation for the rest of the app.  Doesn't shoving a bunch of code into a single `try-catch` go against the idea of handling exceptions as close to where they're thrown as possible?

Comment: @jwalk why is the code being quite long an issue? The idea of handling exceptions 'as close as possible' is 'as few levels up the call stack' as possible. Not 'as few lines away as possible'. It's more important to keep your declarations as local as possible. And there's no reason for f to exist at the point of the catch

Comment: It is very close - it's in the very same function (or even block inside a function, if applicable). Not to mention that in general, you shouldn't have long code in a program. It should be split in multiple functions. These could pass `f` around, if they all need it.

Comment: Okay, so this doesn't work when `... entire code using f ...` is independent of `Foo`, because then if `Foo` throws, then nothing after is reached.  But say I want to **handle** exceptions thrown by Foo and then continue executing the code after it, as if Foo had not failed, otherwise continue as if it had not (and is hence within scope).  That is not possible with this approach.

Comment: @jwalk How can "entire code using `f`" be independent of `Foo`, when `f` is of type `Foo`? I'm seriously confused. Note that if the constructor of `f` fails, `f` will *not* be initialised and if you somehow managed to retain it in scope, *any* access to it would be Undefined Behaviour. Still, even with the dynamic allocation case, if the ctor throws, the allocation and initialisation will *not* take place.

Comment: @Angew Because the instance of `Foo` could just be a object containing a thread that does some background processing and doesn't necessarily interact with other application-level objects.  In that case, you'd want the object to remain alive and **not** be destructed, though it doesn't interact with anything after it.

Comment: @jwalk OK, those are rather specific properties of `Foo` (which you might have mentioned in the original question). In such case, a smart pointer (I'd prefer `std::unique_ptr`) could make sense. You could also look into `std::async` or perhaps Alexandrescu's [`expected<T>`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14923346/1782465).

Comment: @jwalk Not to mention the fact that your original question said "I'd like to catch any exceptions **and return**, otherwise continue using the object" (emphasis mine). This doesn't really match these new thread-based requirements.

Comment: @Angew You're right, I didn't notice that.  The question was not explained as thoroughly as it should have been.

Answer (score 3):

Smart pointers have a `reset` method:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Foo> f;
//...
f.reset(new Foo(...));
```

This solves your "Fail #3" and allows you to do what you want.

Comment: I don't understand why the shared_ptr assignment doesn't work.

Comment: @AnonMail: Because the constructor from pointer for `shared_ptr` is `explicit`.

Comment: @AnonMail: because there is doesn't provide any `operator=(T*)` and the constructor which takes a `T*` is marked `explicit` which forbids automatic conversion. See [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#Synopsis). Now what is the rationale for that design is a whole other question...

Comment: @syam: I suspect to enforce the practice that raw memory allocations should **always** be wrapped in a shared-pointer construct, to avoid mistakes.

Comment: To force people use .reset() or ctor exlicitly for raw pointers, after all that way you pass ownership.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  So I would do what Oli Charlesworth recomends and just do shared_ptr assignment.

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to use  [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) (or C++14's `std::optional`):

```
boost::optional<Foo> f;
try { f = Foo(...); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your smart pointer case and likes work fine if you use the proper .reset() method.

However the question does not fit normal use cases, either the class is misdesigned or you use it incorrectly. Normal use should just go ahead like case#1 with F inside the block. Or without try block and leaving catch to upstream.

EDIT:
Addressing recent comments as well as original issue, I keep my position that try blocks in end-user code are not welcome. For situations where I deal third-party components with certain throw strategy, if it does not fit my needs I write wrappers, converting exception to error-return or error code throwing exception. And use that extended component.

For this case the user is bothered by throwing ctor. So it would be handled by wrapping the ctor in a function:

```
Foo* new_foo( ARGS )
{
    try{
       return new Foo( ARGS );
    }
    catch( const FooException& )
    {
         return NULL;
    }
}
```

Then have the client code free of try blocks, and more importantly, free of assignments. Just `const unique_ptr<Foo> p(new_foo(...))` will do.

Comment: Really?  Avoiding a default constructor is fairly common practice, especially in RAII-like classes...

Comment: I don't agree with your "*does not fit normal use cases*" remark. There are plenty perfectly valid use cases where one can try to instantiate an optional object and continue processing depending on whether instantiation succeeded or failed. The instantiated class doesn't need to be designed specifically for that "optional" use case.

Comment: @syam: so you instantiate it in the try block then. Which is naturally aborted. Why would you want the dead object or any traces outside it?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Of course it is. And in you use RAII, the count of try blocks converges to zero. And in any case, you place them *in* the proper block.  Not like in 2-phase setup. The original form of RAII actually meant the II part.

Comment: @BalogPal: consider some code which is mostly common in all cases, but occasionally branches depending on whether a specific service (the "optional object") is available. Code duplication is not a solution, so you're left either with OP's pattern or designing the class in a way that doesn't fail on construction but sets a checkable flag instead. Both are perfectly acceptable, but I for one prefer OP's pattern: if the class sets a flag instead of throwing then if you wanted to use it in a mandatory way (on the stack) you'd have to check the flag manually which is error-prone.

Comment: @syam: I extended the response reflecting on that

Comment: @BalogPal: +1 I like your wrapper idea. It could even be further extended in the manner of `make_unique / make_shared` with perfect forwarding and directly return a smart pointer, empty or not (naked pointers should be avoided at all costs). Think `make_unique_nothrow / make_shared_nothrow`. The only problem left to make it fully generic would be the `catch` clause: do we `catch(...)` (bad, but maybe necessary)? Provide an exception type as an additional template parameter?