# C++: How to catch exceptions thrown from constructors?

Tags: c++, exception

I have a class, call it `A`, whose constructor takes some input arguments, and may throw an exception if they are incompatible for constructing that object.  In my `main` code, I construct an object of type `A` as follows:

```
A my_obj(arg1,arg2,arg3);
```

and use it.  Obviously if the constructor fails and throws the exception, the execution of the program will be terminated after printing out an 'unhandled exception' message.

I, however, would like to give the user more information in this case and tell him/her why the `exception` has been thrown.  So, I need a way to `catch` the exception.

To this end, one possibility is to enclose the whole code, starting from the declaration of `my_obj` till the end of the program in a `try` block and `catch` the exception afterwards:

```
try {
    A my_obj(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    // ... 
    // about 100 other lines of code being executed if my_obj is created properly 
}
catch (std::exception& e) {
    // print a user-friendly error message and exit
}
```

But this looks to me a bit of an 'overkill'.  Specifically since no other exceptions are thrown in the remaining 100 lines.  Is there any other nicer way to accomplish this?

Comment: Though the following "100 other lines" may access/refer to `my_obj` which they must not if an exception is thrown in its construction. Nice looking is secondary - defined behavior primary.

Comment: So, your question is actually how to catch an exception without the try-catch block?

Comment: @DimChtz, No, I know that it's not possible to catch it without a try/catch block, but I was just wondering if it is possible to only enclose the object creation in such a block.   For example, I could define a pointer 'A* p_obj' outside the block, initialize it inside a try/catch block (ensuring the program halts in case of exception), and then use it again outside the block.

Comment: Please, don't forget the scope of `A my_obj`. (It ends just before `catch`. Your pointer approach does work only if you construct `A` with `new`. ...(as just proposed in the answer of @AndreKampling).

Comment: @Scheff, that's absolutely correct.  I had the same thing in mind.

Comment: no, it's not an overkill if this expresses your logic directly. if you're concerned about covering 100 lines by try/catch, you can put these lines in a function or consider even more decomposition. 100 lines in a single function sounds almost the same suspicious as 100 lines in try/catch

Comment: [Link to similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860775/avoiding-heap-allocation-with-throwing-constructors),although the answers are not great

Comment: It sounds like you have a fundamental design problem and instead of approaching why you have so much code in a single chunk, you look at how to make the syntax easier for you to design poorly.  Sort of a weird XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abstract the object construction into a function that catches the exception:

```
template<typename... Args>
A make_a(Args&&... args) {
    try {
        return A(std::forward(args)...);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        // print a user-friendly error message and exit
        ...
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

// ... in the actual code:
A my_obj = make_a(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

The above makes use of the fact that your program is *exiting* if construction fails. If the requirement were to continue running, the function could return `std::optional<A>` (or its boost equivalent if you don't have access to C++17.)

Comment: What if they don't want to exit the program ?

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks!

Comment: I think you could add std::function parameter to your function to handle exception, then user can pass lambda to do whatever he or she want if exception happens

Comment: @M.M The solution reflects the problem stated in the question, which does specify exiting the program in case of exception. As mentioned in the answer, if this were not the case, then I would recommend the factory function to return `std::optional<A>` or equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be the usage of a pointer (better use a smart pointer such as an [unique_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/) as in below code). You would leave the `unique_ptr` empty, call the constructor in the try block and move the pointer into the `unique_ptr`. After that your other code executes. Surely you have to check for a valid pointer with the [operator bool](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/operator%20bool/) of `unique_ptr` in a simple if statement.
To simplify the usage of `my_obj` a reference is taken: `A& my_obj_ref = *my_obj;`.

```
std::unique_ptr<A> my_obj;
try {
    my_obj = std::move(std::unique_ptr<A>(new A(arg1, arg2, arg3));
}
catch (std::exception& e) {
    // print a user-friendly error message and exit
}

if (my_obj) { // needed if your exception handling doesn't break out of the function
    A& my_obj_ref = *my_obj;

    // ... 
    // about 100 other lines of code being executed if my_obj is created properly
}
```

Remember that this way would allocate your object on the heap instead of the stack.

Comment: I thought of such a solution but then it makes the rest of the code ugly; 'A' has some operators like operator[], that I would need to use in the rest of the code.  With pointers it would look like '(*my_obj)[index]' instead of 'my_obj[index]'

Comment: @PBM define a reference after the catch block

Comment: Since he is using object, it would be better to use operator bool method in that class so that he can use that object in if condition to determine it's validity

Comment: @AndreKampling I would mention the stack vs. heap storage. (I prefer stack storage whenever appropriate.)

Comment: @Asesh that is generally considered bad style because it means all the rest of the code using the object has to have ugly tests

Answer (score 2):

If the constructor throws, you don't have an object. `std::optional<>` is a type that means "We might not have an object here".

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
std::optional<T> try_make(Args&& ... args)
{ try {
    return make_optional(std::forward(args...));
} catch (...) {
    return {};
} }
```

Then

```
auto my_obj = try_make<A>(arg1,arg2,arg3);
if (my_obj) {
    // about 100 other lines of code being executed if my_obj is created properly
}
```

Comment: `std::forward(args...)` doesn't compile, did you mean `std::forward(args)...`? Also, `make_optional(<...>)` should probably be `std::make_optional(T(<...>))` or just `T(<...>)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here, depending on how you want control to continue if the construction fails.

---

If you want to exit the function by throwing an exception, then you don't need to do anything, you can let the `A` construction exception propagate up.

If you want to exit by either throwing a different exception, or by performing some actions before letting the `A` construction exception propagate, then use a factory function (perhaps a lambda) that performs those actions, e.g.:

```
auto a_factory(T x, U y) -> A     // or use perfect forwarding
{
    try { return A(x, y);  }
    catch(...) {
         log("constructing A failed...");
         throw other_exception();
    } 
}

// ... 
     A my_obj = a_factory(x, y);
```

---

If you want to exit by returning a value, then you could still use the above method, but wrap the calling function in another function that catches expected exceptions and returns a value.

Or you could use the `optional` (below) or `unique_ptr` (as covered by other answers) technique, but executing a `return` statement from the `catch` block.

---

If you want to continue execution without a valid `A`, then you can do:

```
std::optional<A> opt_my_obj;
try
{
    A temp(...args...);
    opt_my_obj.swap(temp);
} catch(...)
{
    // handling, you could return from the function here
}

// At this point you can test `if ( opt_my_obj )` to branch the flow.
// When you're at a point where you have verified the object exists, you 
// can enable normal object syntax by writing:

A& my_obj = *opt_my_obj;
```

---

If you have several objects in your function that need this consideration, I would tend to suggest the version of having the whole function wrapped in a try...catch that can handle all the different exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do it *simple*: Throw the human readable message. This strategy works well when there is no choice, and usually, there isn't. There is a catch though, you want exception handling to be reasonably robust, so I package the message inside a `std::array<char,4096>` truncating if necessary and remembering the zero-terminator (I know that this could blow the stack but it should be fine if we are not in a recursive function), and throw that.

Example:

```
try
    {
    Options opts(argv);
    SomeResource resource(opts.someParameter());
    //...More actions that could throw
    }
catch(const std::array<char,4096>& errmessage) //Or rather some other type that contains the message.
    {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s\n",errmessage.data());
    return -1; //Or any non-zero value
    }
return 0;
```

Pros:

- Quick to implement new constructors for new classes since there is *one* exception class only, that will works for everything
- You will pick up any system messages right from the source

Cons:

- Lack of context: The message will have to say something like "It was not possible to open the file foo: No such file or directory.". Without telling the user what the root cause for the exception. This problem is inherited from the exception model and cannot be solved without treating exceptions as glorified error codes
- If you want to branch on exception content, you must parse the message, but I find this rarely needed. Possibly in the context of a compiler, but that would print that message anyway `foo:54:1: Error: bar is not a baz`.