# Can I / Should I use std::exception's for regular error handling?

Tags: c++, error-handling, idioms

I'm going to start this new project in C++ and am thinking about an un-painful way to do error handling. Now, I'm not going to start out throwing and catching exceptions, and will quite possibly never throw exceptions at all, but I was thinking - even for regular error handling, why roll my own / copy-paste a class for describing errors/status, when I could just use `std::exception` and its child classes (Or perhaps an `std::optional<std::exception>`)?

```
using Status = std::optional<std::exception>;
Status somethingThatMayFail(int x);
```

Is anybody/any project working this way? Is it a ridiculous idea or just a bit creaky?

Comment: @vsoftco: See edit. I'm talking about no-exception-throwing error handling.

Comment: Interesting... I recently heard that Google seems to be using such a system, not sure if true or not. What if your functions must return something? Will you use a pair/tuple?

Comment: @vsoftco: Let's not go into specifics... the question is just about what to use for reporting errors. But - either the function will have an in/out parameter (reference or pointer), or maybe it'll return some case-class (I'm sure C++ has something like that by now  that's better than C unions).

Comment: It's an interesting question, I haven't seen exceptions used the way you propose, but I look forward for seeing an answer to your question. But imo you are kind of not using exceptions where they are most useful: namely in RAII, where you make sure a proper destructor is called via stack unwinding. Your proposed way is in a sense similar to the C-way of doing things, like returning error codes.

Comment: You may want to check out [Alexandrescu's Expected<T>](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Andrei-Alexandrescu-Systematic-Error-Handling-in-C)

Comment: @vsoftco: A lot of C++ code uses 'the C way' - returning status codes - for various reasons. One of them is sort-of-forcing the calling coder to handle errors right after the call.

Comment: @Thomas: So you're suggesting Expected<void>  for the no outputs case?

Comment: Never saw something like that, if you want the best of both worlds you should checkout the boost exception library.

Comment: Never saw something like that, if you want the best of both worlds you should checkout the boost exception library.

I also think you may need a mix of optional and variant to support return types in the success case.

I'm not so experienced with special hardware and I assume you have a good reason to not use exceptions but if you use stl or boost: Those both may throw exceptions in your program.

Jon Kalb convinced me that exceptions are the way to handle errors in the default case: http://www.exceptionsafecode.com/

(EDIT did not work)

Comment: I think one argument against using exceptions as simple return values is that it is *anti-idiomatic*. Already in the comments here, there were misunderstandings about what you are doing. You are misleading every reader of your code. (<irony>Why not use task objects, or file handles?</irony>).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should construct exceptions unless you actually intend to throw them. I would recommend a bool or enum return type. The intent will be much clearer to someone reading your code, and they will be faster. However, if you construct an exception, someone else will come along and think they can throw the exception and cause the whole system to crash.

C++ exceptions play an important role in resource management, triggering destructors and all that (RAII). Using them any other way is going to hurt performance and (more importantly) confuse the holy heck out of anyone trying to maintain the code, later.

You can, however, do what you want with a status reporting class that does NOT have anything to do with std::exception. People do way too much for "faster" code when they don't need to. If a status enum isn't good enough, and you need to return more info, then a status reporting class will work. If it makes the code easier to read, then go for it.

Just don't call it an exception unless you actually throw it.

Comment: This. Even if `optional<exception>` is perfect for the use case, using it outside of a throw/catch context will be confusing. Confusion should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think that performance alone might prove problematic. Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <boost/optional.hpp>   


int return_code_foo(int i)   
{
    if(i < 10)  
        return -1;
    return 0;
} 


std::logic_error return_exception_foo(int i)   
{
    if(i < 10)  
        return std::logic_error("error");
    return std::logic_error("");
} 


boost::optional<std::logic_error> return_optional_foo(int i)   
{
    if(i < 10)  
        return boost::optional<std::logic_error>(std::logic_error("error"));
    return boost::optional<std::logic_error>();
} 


void exception_foo(int i)   
{
    if(i < 10)  
        throw std::logic_error("error");
} 


int main()
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;

    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for(size_t i = 11; i < 9999999; ++i)
        return_code_foo(i);
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "code elapsed time: " << (end - start).count() << "s\n";

    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for(size_t i = 11; i < 9999999; ++i)
        return_exception_foo(i);
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "exception elapsed time: " << (end - start).count() << "s\n";

    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for(size_t i = 11; i < 9999999; ++i)
        return_optional_foo(i);
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "optional elapsed time: " << (end - start).count() << "s\n";

    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for(size_t i = 11; i < 9999999; ++i)
        exception_foo(i);
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "exception elapsed time: " << (end - start).count() << "s\n";

    return 0;
}
```

On my CentOS, using gcc 4.7, it timed at:

```
[amit@amit tmp]$ ./a.out 
code elapsed time: 39893s
exception elapsed time: 466762s
optional elapsed time: 215282s
exception elapsed time: 38436s
```

in vanilla settings, and:

```
[amit@amit tmp]$ ./a.out 
code elapsed time: 0s
exception elapsed time: 238985s
optional elapsed time: 33595s
exception elapsed time: 24350
```

at -O2 settings.

P.S. I personally would use exceptions/stack-unwinding due to a belief that it is a fundamental part of C+, possibly as @vsoftco said above.

Comment: Well, yes, point taken,  but you were measuring the time when an error actually occurs, not when it doesn't. Also, if my error handling code, using a numeric status code, were to pass a string somewhere, or write it to a stream, that would equate the running times I would think.

Comment: @einpoklum Actually, I disagree - if you check the code, the "exception" never occurred in this test. That's exactly the problem with this approach - it seems tremendously expensive for the normal case. This also applies to your point about the actual handling of errors - it tends to be much less frequent. ( If you think about it, yeshpomashehu :-) )

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, this is not a ridiculous idea and you can actually use `std::exception` for regular error handling; with some caveats.

**Using `std::exception` as the result of the function**

Let's say that a function can exit in several error states:

```
std::exception f( int i )
{
  if (i > 10)
    return std::out_of_range( "Index is out of range" );

  if ( can_do_f() )
    return unexpected_operation( "Can't do f in the current state" );

  return do_the_job();
}
```

How can you handle this with a `std::exception` or an optional one? When the function returns, a copy of the exception will be created, keeping only the `std::exception` part and dismissing the specifics of the actual error; leaving you with the only information that "yep, something went wrong…". The behavior would be the same as returning a boolean or an optional of the expected result type, if any.

**Using `std::exception_ptr` to save the specifics**

Another solution would be to apply the same approach than in [std::promise](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_exception), that is to return an `std::exception_ptr`. There you will be able to return either nothing or an exception, while keeping the actual error details. Restoring the actual type of the error may still be tricky.

**Returning the error or the result in the same object**

Finally another option would be to use the `Expected<T>` [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4109.pdf),  and [its implementation](https://github.com/ptal/expected). There you will be able to return the value or the error in a single object and to handle the error has you wish (by testing the error or with regular exception handling), with some particularities for the case of a function returning no value (more on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923346/how-would-you-use-alexandrescus-expectedt-with-void-functions) or on [this blog](http://anto-nonco.blogspot.fr/2013/03/extending-expected-to-deal-with.html])).

**How to choose**

My personal opinion on the matter is that if you are going to use exceptions, then use them the way they have been designed, eventually with some extra tools like `Expected<T>` to make it easier. Otherwise, if you cannot use the standard exception handling, then go for a solution which has proven itself, like the classical error codes system.